# Output to DOS using C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

``` I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I am trying to change the timen on my PC to 11 pm the ``day before yesterday. My question is can somebody tell me what statement that will allow ``me to output directly to DOS using C#. ```

Sorry for the poorly written question. I was trying to change the time to 11:50 two days ago. I am not familar with programming in Windows I have always used Linux. In linux I would execute my file from the command line and output to the command line. But using Visual Studio I was not sure if outputting to the command line would output to Visual Studio or MS DOS. If there is a way of changing the timecin this way I would appreciate it.

In command propt I entered `date 28/07/2010` and it changed the date but when I entered `Console.WriteLine("date 28/07/2010")` into Visual Studio 2010 the time stayed the same. Is this statement not outputting to the command prompt.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What does changing your time on the PC have to do with outputting to DOS from C#?

Comment: What do you really want to know?  How to print to the command line, or change the time?

Comment: DOS is no longer a part of Windows, and hasn't been for almost 10 years. Do you mean the command prompt?

Comment: "In command propt I entered date 28/07/2010 and it changed the date but when I entered Console.WriteLine("date 28/07/2010") into Visual Studio 2010 the time stayed the same. Is this statement not outputting to the command prompt." This is just C#'s version of printf() or cout << "text" << endl. None of these are going to do anything other than print some text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

...assuming your application is started from the Command Line.

If you're trying to execute something from the command line (rather than outputing to the command line), then you want:

```
DateTime yesterdayAtEleven = 
    DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("d") + " 11:00PM");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("date", yesterdayAtEleven.ToString());
```

[System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Comment: I am using a 64bit version of Windows 7 and it says file cannot be found. A Win32 Exception. Do you think this is because I am using a 64 bit system? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("time 23:59");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, but if you made a Console app, you'd use System.Console.WriteLine

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx